modulus maths question - competitive programming
I was attempting past competition questions and was stuck on this question. The solution was made public, but I still can't seem to get how did they derive the solution logic.
question:

Meow is fascinated with numbers. One day, bored at class, he started jotting down numbers on his textbook. With no particular reason, he only writes down numbers with 3 digits or above, denoted as N
. He chops off the last digit of the number and then forms a new number, M
. Then he performed a mathematical operation: S=N−M
, and then he tells you S
.


Later, you found out that the number N
is actually a super magical number that is the solution to life, the universe, and everything. Can you figure the number out?


Input:
The first line contains a single integer t
(1≤t≤1000)
– the number of test cases.


Each test cases contains a single positive integer, S
(100≤S≤1017)


Output:
For each test case, output a line containing the possible values for N
. If there exists multiple possible values, output all in ascending order separated by a single space.


Example
inputCopy
3
100
500
1800

outputCopy
111
555
1999 2000


solution:
t = int(input())

for _ in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    
    last_digit = n % 9
    x = (n - last_digit) // 9
    
    if last_digit == 0:
        print((x - 1) * 10 + 9, x * 10)
    else:
        print(x * 10 + last_digit)

Does anyone know what does 9 have to do with these inputs? Like what was the thought process that leads to figuring out this solution?

Please include all relevant data in the question itself. Supplementary links are welcome, but links that are necessary to understand the question are not. In addition, please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Obvioudly, the answer is 42. No math needed.

@Yunnosch the answer depends on the input

Your question does not match your input nor the answer.

@Enigmativity it does, the first test case, given s = 100, the output will be n = 111. Logic behind this is if n=111,  m = 11, hence 111-11=100.

@JiaYeeChong - Your question says "Input: The first line contains a single integer t (1≤t≤1000) – the number of test cases". That's nothing to do with s, n, nor m, nor is it in the range of values you're talking about.

isn't the last digit of the number n n % 10, not n % 9?

We have an unknown N, its last digit
L = N % 10 and
M = N // 10
Given
S = N - M
Follows that
N = 10 * M + L
We can write:
S = 10 * M + L - M = 9 * M + L
So
M = S // 9
L = S % 9

and
N = 10 * M + L = 10 * S // 9 + S % 9

That's the origin of 9 in OP code.
